# Angular 6: Debug library with Typescript while "ng serve" the main angular app

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, angular6, source-maps

Right now I am debugging my library as one single huge file in JavaScript located in the fems5 folder.

I have the library source code, and the .js.map in the fems2 folder, but I don't know how to link them to the source code and debug viewing Typescript instead.

I have tried:

1. npm link
2. combinations of settings in angular.json build and serve like "vendorSourceMap", "sourceMap", "preserveSymlinks"
3. tsconfig.json options like "sourceRoot", "mapRoot", "paths"

But I couldn't and I cant find any documentation referring only to version 6, to know if I am using them properly.

**Is it possible? With npm link or without it? by changing some path? copying the source somewhere?**

Library:

[image]

Application:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Is your Application and Library hosted under single application?

Comment: No, 2 different applications